# How can i convert the string to date and date from string?

Tags: iphone, nsdateformatter

My Input String is

```
NSString *inputString=@"15 February 2012 17:05";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM YYYY HH:mm"];
NSDate *dateVal = [dateFormat dateFromString:inputString];

NSDateFormatter *dateFormat2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat2 setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm"];
NSString *outputString = [dateFormat2 stringFromDate:dateVal];
[dateFormat release];
[dateFormat2 release];
```

I got the following date 
outputString=12/25/2011 17:05

But it should be 02/15/2012 17:05..Where did i do the mistake?

Comment: The problem is in the first part (the parsing of the date string).  It's returning Dec 25, 2011, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using wrong format for date format and also there is no need to create another instance of NSDateFormatter -

```
    NSString *inputString=@"15 February 2012 17:05"; 
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm"]; 
    NSDate *dateVal = [dateFormat dateFromString:inputString];

    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"];
    NSString *outputString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:dateVal];
```

Answer (score 4):

The date format is incorrect, use:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm"];
```

Capital "YYYY" is for use in "Week of Year" based calendars.

See: unicode [Date_Format_Patterns](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/#Date_Format_Patterns)

BTW, an `NSLog` of `dateVal` would have shown that the problem was on the input formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Does your locale correspond to the format you are trying to parse? By default NSDateFormatter uses current locale.

Answer (score 0):

The input date format should be:

```
 [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd MMMM yyyy HH:mm"];
```